# JSON: Fetch id from json while redirecting login.html to homepage.html

Tags: jquery, html, json

In given code, after login from index.html page to  homepage.html,

```
for eg: name = Student
    password = 123
```

then in homepage.html body tag value should be like

```
<html>
<body id="student1">

this is home page.

</body>
</html>
```

which can be set from json file. If uname = controller then id should be "cntOne".
Help me with some sort of code.

```
json:
{
"Student" : [ { "uName"  : "student1", "upass" : "123", "id":"student1" },], "controller":[{ "uName"  : "cntOne", "upass" : "123", "id":"cntOne"  },]    
}

**index.html:**

<input type="text"> 
<input type="password"> 
<button>Submit</button>

**homepage.html:**
<html>
<body id="">
    this is home page.
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: getting id?try this `data = {
  "Student": [{
    "uName": "student1",
    "upass": "123",
    "id": "student1"
  }, ],
  "controller": [{
    "uName": "cntOne",
    "upass": "123",
    "id": "cntOne"
  }, ]
}

console.log(data['Student'][0]['id'])`

Comment: do you want to read id from json and then set it as `body` id?

Comment: @Aminur Rashid yeah,it's true.Do you have any reference to solve it?

Comment: can you elaborate this line a bit more: "If uname = controller then id should be "cntOne""

Comment: @Aminur Rashid  if key = student means student is going to login. For specific student like "student1" it will return id "studnet1". For key = controller means admin is going to login.  For specific controller like "cntOne" it will return id "cntOne".

Comment: so, the json variable will contain either Student or controller?

Comment: @Aminur Rashid yes

Comment: @guradio where to write this code to fetch id? console.log(data['Student'][0]['id'])

Comment: @PandeyRashmi did you try the whole code you do it as is you initialize your json to a var then use that var. in my case i use var data = your json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added a snippet here, and use alert to show the changed id of div.

```js
var json = {
  "Student": [{
    "uName": "student1",
    "upass": "123",
    "id": "student1"
  }]
};
if (json["Student"]) {
  $('#myDiv').attr('id', json["Student"][0].id);
  alert($('div').first().attr('id'));
} else if (json["controller"]) {
  $('#myDiv').attr('id', json["controller"][0].id);
  alert($('div').first().attr('id'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv">

</div>
```